# Ubuntu login black screen after postgis install

Tags: graphics, login-screen, postgresql, gis

I just built a new computer running an ASUS P8Z77-V LK motherboard with no graphics card.  Can boot into Ubuntu, run a bunch of the usual programs (Chrome, etc) no problem.

However, when I install postgis through the ubuntugis/ppa, things start to go downhill.  PostGIS actually works fine, but the problem comes when I shut down the computer.  When I boot back up, the screen flashes black a few times, I briefly see a login terminal prompt, and then I'm just faced with a black screen and a blinking white cursor (where there should be the usual ubuntu login screen).

Strangely, typing in my password and hitting enter (although nothing shows up on the screen) logs me in and brings up the Ubuntu desktop.  However, the performance of some key programs is negatively affected.  For example, the tabs in Chrome get weirdly faded and occasionally the web pages will just freak out (tons of small multicolored lines across the screen, big black bars across parts of the screen, etc), especially when I switch tabs or scroll.

I'm able to totally eliminate this issue (can boot into normal login screen and no chrome freakouts) by uninstalling postgis and autoremoving the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get -y remove qgis postgresql postgis postgresql-9.1-postgis postgresql-client
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgraphicsmagick3 postgresql-9.1 python-numpy libxine1-x libproj0
  odbcinst1debian2 python-qgis-common libqt4-test libqt4-designer libqwt5-qt4
  libogdi3.2 libspatialindex1 python-central libcoin60 libavdevice53 odbcinst
  liblapack3gf libxine1-plugins libmysqlclient18 python-qgis libarmadillo2
  libdap11 libgdal1-1.7.0 libqt4-help python-qt4 libgdal1 python-sip
  libepsilon0 qgis-providers libgif4 libxerces-c28 libopenthreads14
  libhdf5-serial-1.8.4 libgeos-c1 gdal-bin postgresql-common proj-data
  libxine1-console libfreexl1 qgis-common postgresql-client-9.1
  libqtassistantclient4 libspatialite3 libzip2 libblas3gf proj-bin
  libxine1-misc-plugins libgeos-3.2.2 libgeos-3.3.8 python-gdal
  postgresql-client-common libpq5 libosgearth1 libqgis1.8.0 libodbc1
  libgsl0ldbl libqt4-scripttools libqtwebkit4 libhdf4-0-alt
  qgis-plugin-globe-common qgis-providers-common mysql-common
  libopenscenegraph80 libdapclient3 libxine1-bin libxine1-ffmpeg libnetcdf6
  libxine1
```

So... how do I run postgis on my machine without these bad side-effects?